# 403 Forbidden after installing ssl via certbot Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, lets-encrypt

I installed the DigitalOcean rails image as [shown here](https://do.co/2GTOVjB)

I then followed the instructions for installing `letscrypt ssl` and I got that working. However, once the SSL implementation worked, I started getting a 403 error on the homepage. here is the error log:

```
2022/05/16 00:06:39 [error] 783#783: *11 directory index of "/home/rails/xxx-boxes/public/" is forbidden, client: x.x.x.142, server: xxx-boxes.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "x.x.x.62"
```

I am not sure what I should put for root on a rails server, should it be `/home/rails/xxx.boxes`, `/home/rails/xxx.boxes/public` or something else?

Or is it another config issue causing the 403 error? I did try doing `chmod 775` on the `xxx.boxes` folder but it made no difference. I restarted the droplet after making those changes also so its not that either. Any ideas?

My files are in `/home/rails/xxx.boxes` (i used xxx to obscure the name if it wasn't obvious)

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/rails**

```
server {
listen   80;
root /home/rails/xxx-boxes/public;
server_name xxx-boxes.com;
index index.htm index.html;

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/xxx-boxes.com**

```
server {

    root /home/rails/xxx-boxes/public;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name xxx-boxes.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx-boxes.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by 

Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx-boxes.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {

        root /home/rails/xxx-boxes/public;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name www.xxx-boxes.com; # managed by Certbot


        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx-boxes.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx-boxes.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot




}server {
    if ($host = xxx-boxes.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name xxx-boxes.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}server {
    if ($host = www.xxx-boxes.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name www.xxx-boxes.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

/etc/nginx/sites-available/rails

server {
    listen   80;
    root /home/rails/xxx-boxes/public;
    server_name xxx-boxes.com;
    index index.htm index.html;

        location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
        }

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

and in **sites-available** it shows:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 May 11 17:55 rails -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/rails
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 May 15 22:19 xxx-boxes.com -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/xxx-boxes.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually run certbot's script to install/renew my certificates:
`certbot --force-renew` should bring the list of sites you have configured to either Nginx or Apache.